# Remove dropdown arrow in React Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

i´m trying to remove the dropdown arrow with this following css, but it´s not making any effect.

[image]

```
.dropdown::after{
  display: none !important; 
}
```

here is the code

```
<NavDropdown className={classes.user} title="Componentes" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
   <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
   <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
   <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
   <NavDropdown.Divider />
   <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

Comment: Maybe, try this selector `.dropdown-toggle:after` to remove the arrow.

Comment: Junaid appears to be correct, more info here:
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/341

Answer (score 18):

Here is the CSS from the Bootstrap dropdown arrow:
[image]

So in order to overwrite it you need to use the corresponding CSS selector:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Note that maybe there is no need to include the `!important`.

Comment: How is the down arrow being specified? In the image you linked, it has `content: ""`, but the empty string is somehow becoming a down arrow. I inspected the element but can't find any other ::after usages. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @Nathan The triangle is created by the borders' properties, not by the content value. You can see the details of how it works in this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/